# Check if name attribute already exists in CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an entity called `BankInfo`, and one of its parameters is `name` which is a string. I'm just wondering, is there a way in `CoreData` to check and see if a `name` already exists in `BankInfo` without having to retrieve every `BankInfo` object and cycle through them individually and check? What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a *fetch request* with a *predicate* to find objects matching certain attributes.
If you are only interested in the *existence*
of an object with the given key, use `countForFetchRequest` instead of actually fetching the objects, and limit the result set to one object:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"BankInfo"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", theName]];
[request setFetchLimit:1];
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (count == NSNotFound)
    // some error occurred
else if (count == 0)
    // no matching object
else
    // at least one matching object exists
```

Comment: So once youve determined that atleast one matching object exists, how would you then go about retrieving that object efficiently without having to grab all the entities and then filtering through them?

Comment: @Pavan: If you are interested in the object itself (and not only the existence) then you would use a normal `executeFetchRequest` directly and not `countForFetchRequest`.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, gotcha. I just reread the post and realise that the poster is asking about checking 'if something' exists. Gotcha. Sorry pump up my post, is there anyway you could have a look at the following post that Ive posted please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354211/core-data-issue-with-migration-policy-after-creating-mapping-model

Answer (score 12):

For other, who like me, ended up here looking for **Swift 3** solution, here it is:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "BankInfo")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", theName)
request.predicate = predicate
request.fetchLimit = 1

do{
    let count = try managedContext.count(for: request)   
    if(count == 0){
    // no matching object
    }
    else{
    // at least one matching object exists
    }
  }
catch let error as NSError {
     print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
```

Comment: I just made this into a `NSManagedObjectContext` extension that returns a `Bool`:    `func checkEntityWithAttrExists(entity: String, attr: String, val: String) -> Bool {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(attr) == %@", val)`

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 5** use the below code, it similar to one of the upvoted answers, the only difference being use context.count instead of managedContext.count

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<MachineTypeTolerance> = MachineTypeTolerance.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "machineType = %@", type)
request.predicate = predicate
request.fetchLimit = 1
do{
    let count = try context.count(for: request)
    //instead of managedContext use context,
    // where let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    if(count == 0){
        print("no matches")
    }
    else{
        print("match found")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```