# How to check if core data is empty

Tags: swift, core-data

How do I check if core data is empty using Swift. I tried this method:

```
var people = [NSManagedObject]()

if people == nil {

}
```

but this results in this error:

> “binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type [NSManagedObject] and nil”

Comment: `people` isn't an optional, so it can't be `nil`.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. I don't understand what you want to test. At the moment you create an object and check if it is nil. This makes no sense.

Comment: people is just an array, so you should check if this array is empty.
people.isEmpty

Comment: Swift Array syntax - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html
`var people` - is an empty array of `NSManagedObject`

Comment: @dasdom are you kidding? How is `people` anything *but* an array (of `NSManagedObject`s)

Comment: @KostiantynKoval I was wrong. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if the Core Database is empty you have to make a `NSFetchRequest` on the entity you want to check, and check if the results of the request are empty.

**You can check it with this function:**

```
func entityIsEmpty(entity: String) -> Bool
{

    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context = NSManagedObjectContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    var error = NSErrorPointer()

    var results:NSArray? = self.context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error)

    if let res = results
    {
        if res.count == 0
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return true
    }

}
```

**Or simplier and shorter solution: (using `.countForFetchRequest`)**

```
func entityIsEmpty(entity: String) -> Bool
{

    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context = NSManagedObjectContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    var error = NSErrorPointer()

    var results:NSArray? = self.context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error)

    var count = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: error)

    if error != nil
    {
        println("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        if count == 0
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You should always check the *return value* to test for success or not, not the error variable. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/29602330/1187415.

Comment: Thanks for the note, its always bad to force unwrap optional values.

Comment: If you only want to check if any object of the entity exists (without actually fetching them) then it is more efficient to use `countForFetchRequest`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794757/check-if-name-attribute-already-exists-in-coredata.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the answer!

Comment: Again: `if error != nil` is *not* the correct way to check for an error condition ...

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3 solution:**

```
var isEmpty: Bool {
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: YOUR_ENTITY)
        let count  = try context.count(for: request)
        return count == 0
    } catch {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need that ternary operator you can just return `count == 0`

Answer (score 6):

Based on Dejan Skledar's answer I got rid of some compiler warnings and adopted it to Swift 2.0.

```
func entityIsEmpty(entity: String) -> Bool
{

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext()
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    var results : NSArray?

    do {
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        return results.count == 0

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return true
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure if the `if let res=results` clause along with its `else` clause ist required or not.

Comment: In Swift 2 `executeFetchRequest` returns a non-optional `[AnyObject]`. The recommended syntax is: `var results = [NSManagedObject]()` ... `results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]` or the appropriate subclass, the `if let - else` expression is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mend this. Although the `as! [NSManagedObject]()` is not required just to find out if there is anything in yet.

Comment: If you want to get only the number of items use the method `countForFetchRequest:error:` (instead of `do - executeFetchRequest... - catch`). It returns an `Int`

Answer (score 4):

**SwiftUI Solution**

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

   @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyObject.created, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
   private var myobjects: FetchedResults<MyObject>

   var body: some View {
    if self.myobjects.isEmpty{
        Text("There are no objects in the current database.")
    }
    else{
        // whatever
    }
   }
}
```