# How can i check if data is successfully stored in coredata, next time when i launch an app ? - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have successfully fetched data through api and stored them in coredata. 
Now next time when user launches an app i want to check if there is local data available then i want to load local data, not server data.

Comment: read data from your CoreData table. If the data is present it was fetched properly else its not there read from server

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769826/how-to-check-if-the-core-data-was-empty-swift

Answer (score 0):

You should apply two things for fulfilling your scenario.

**1) First Fetch Data from CoreData.**

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
               print(data.value(forKey: "username") as! String)
          }

        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
```

if result is available then Don't need to call API.

**2)If Fetched Result is nil Call the API and Save Data Into CoreData**